# How to hide all the items on desktop

Tags: desktop-background, .desktop

How to hide all the items on desktop? I have set up a beautiful desktop background and I want to see the full desktop sometimes. Any shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in gsettings (& dconf-editor):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Comment: This is cool. But there is only one issue, after I hide all the items. My windows key is disabled when I am in desktop. Any workaround?

Comment: after 10 seconds of googling I found this: http://blog.angeloff.name/post/2012/08/08/ubuntu-12-04-super-key-not-working-in-shortcuts/

Comment: @王子1986 this seems to be your problem ,but it is not solved http://askubuntu.com/questions/328695/cant-use-keybinds-when-desktop-icons-are-hidden-and-theres-no-active-window

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Unity-Tweak-Tool

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Run it and set in System -> Desktop Shortcuts

   Show Shortcuts: O

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu tweak Tool as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Open it from the Unity Launcher and go to tweaks tab and 
Click on Desktop icons

[image]
Toggle the Desktop icon visibility

[image]